# How to coerce date type for variables in dataframe using dplyr and a helper function in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, stringr

I have a dataframe consisting of 50 variables. For simplicity, I have created a dataframe of 5 variables. I want the variables in position 2:5 to be coerced as date variables instead of character variables.

```
ID<-1:3
ASSISTANCEPERIODFROM<-c("14/06/2009", "13/01/2010","13/01/2010")
ASSISTANCEPERIODTO<-c("14/06/2009","30/06/2010","30/06/2010")
APPROVEDDATE<-c("14/11/2009","30/12/2010","30/01/2011")
DATEOFBIRTH<-c("14/11/1990","30/12/1970","30/01/2000")

df<-data.frame(ID,ASSISTANCEPERIODFROM,ASSISTANCEPERIODTO,APPROVEDDATE,DATEOFBIRTH,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I tried the `mutate_each` function in dplyr, along with the helper function, `contains`, but when I tried for two strings, I could not get the results I want. The two strings are `PERIOD` and `DATE`. Below are my method.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

df<-df %>%
       mutate_each(funs(dmy(.)),contains(c("PERIOD","DATE")))
# Error: is.string(match) is not TRUE

df<-df %>%
       mutate_each(funs(dmy(.)),contains("PERIOD"|"DATE"))
# Error in "PERIOD" | "DATE" : 
#   operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

df<-df %>%
       mutate_each(funs(dmy(.)),contains("PERIOD|DATE"))
# No error but doesn not give me what I want

df<-df %>%
       mutate_each(funs(dmy(.)),as.numeric(str_detect(colnames(df),"PERIOD|DATE")))
```

I also tried my luck at `str_detect` but it would not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note a few things:

- Use `mutate_at` instead of `mutate_each` since the latter is deprecated.
- Use `matches` instead of `contains` and wrap the whole thing in `vars` as mandated in the latest releases of `dplyr`
- Use `as.Date` (method for `character` input) with the `format` argument to parse the dates

All of that results in this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

df_foo = data_frame(
  ID = 1:3,
  ASSISTANCEPERIODFROM = c("14/06/2009", "13/01/2010","13/01/2010"),
  ASSISTANCEPERIODTO = c("14/06/2009","30/06/2010","30/06/2010"),
  APPROVEDDATE = c("14/11/2009","30/12/2010","30/01/2011"),
  DATEOFBIRTH = c("14/11/1990","30/12/1970","30/01/2000")
)

df_foo %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(
    .cols = vars(dplyr::matches("(PERIOD)|(DATE)")),
    funs(
      as.Date.character(., format = "%d/%m/%Y")
    )
  ) 
# A tibble: 3 × 5
     ID ASSISTANCEPERIODFROM ASSISTANCEPERIODTO APPROVEDDATE DATEOFBIRTH
  <int>               <date>             <date>       <date>      <date>
1     1           2009-06-14         2009-06-14   2009-11-14  1990-11-14
2     2           2010-01-13         2010-06-30   2010-12-30  1970-12-30
3     3           2010-01-13         2010-06-30   2011-01-30  2000-01-30
```

Comment: When I went to `dplyr` documentation, they only list `mutate`, `mutate_`, `transmute` and `transmute_`. So, when can I find the different `mutate` functions? Thanks!

Comment: @HNSKD Which version of `dplyr` are you running? These are in the [latest `>=0.5.0` versions](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/).

Comment: Hey, why wouldn't the same thing happen for `na_if`? For example, `y <- c("abc", "def", "", "ghi")`. I want to test na_if(y,matches("def|abc")), it returns me the original vector

Comment: @HNSKD You have to add parentheses to match groups: `(def)|(abc)`.

Comment: I tried `na_if(y,matches("(abc)|(def)"))`, but it returns an error 
`Error: `y` must be length 1 or same length as `x``

Comment: @HNSKD I think that you are using `na_if` wrong. The second argument to `na_if` does not accept regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question:

```
df[2:5] <- lapply(df[2:5], as.Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

No need for `dplyr`
But looking at what your trying to do it seems that you want only variable which have "DATE" or "PERIOD" in the name to be convert ?

Comment: Why wouldnt this return a list?

Comment: @HNSKD This does return a dataframe. What about a list, I don't understand ?

Comment: I meant, from what I understand, `lapply` returns a list. So when I tried your code and it gave a dataframe, I was quite surprised. Do you know why it returns a dataframe instead?

Comment: @HNSKD `help(data.frame)`, section Details: A data frame is a **list** of variables of the same number ... you can also try `is.list(df)` to test if df is a list..

Answer (score 1):

`contains` doesn't deal with `regex`, so it doesn't detect any column containing `PERIOD|DATE`. Try:

```
df %>% mutate_each(funs(dmy(.)),union(contains("PERIOD"),contains("DATE")))
#  ID ASSISTANCEPERIODFROM ASSISTANCEPERIODTO APPROVEDDATE DATEOFBIRTH
#1  1           2009-06-14         2009-06-14   2009-11-14  1990-11-14
#2  2           2010-01-13         2010-06-30   2010-12-30  1970-12-30
#3  3           2010-01-13         2010-06-30   2011-01-30  2000-01-30
```

Otherwise, just use `matches`:

```
df %>% mutate_each(funs(dmy(.)),matches("PERIOD|DATE"))
```

to get the same result.